# Move currency symbol to left at each input keeping it aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a input tag and a currency symbol. 
On entering any number or backspace, I want the Currency symbol and Amount to be center- aligned that is currency symbol should move left and right accordingly

Attaching code and screenshot

```
<div class="input">
    <div class="a">
        <span>₹</span>
        <input class="inActive" id="v" value="" type="number" required>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Required Result :-
[image]

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use bootstrap and do something like that

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">₹</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
</div>
```

It will put your sign in an add-on on the left side of the input.

Comment: To be accessible, the input needs a suitable label element with more informative content than "amount". It will be more informative for others, too. ;-)

Comment: The question is  approximative and rough, so is my answer. Hope you'll understand it. He asks for design, I show you a way to do it. :)